# subdomain error redirects to main site using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This question was asked before here, but no solution was found. i have the same problem. any non existant subdomain gets redirected to my hosts site

would like to redirect from not existing subdomains to error page or to main domain. I have a lot of subdomains and they are created and deleted dynamically so I do not control the process and do not know what exactly subdomains are created or deleted right now.

If one user deletes his subdomain I would like to redirect visitors to main domain or just show error page with custom message, the same like it's made by blogspot.com:

Lets say if you type any not existing subdomain it shows you error page that says that subdomain page does not exist

Comment: it must be the default virtual host [`<VirtualHost *:*> ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/</VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) in the main config.

Comment: Thanks Deadooshka, where do i find the main config file. can i configure it in the htaccess file if i dont have access to the main config file.

Comment: It's a [`httpd.conf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#main) by default. `VirtualHost` allowed only in server context. `.htaccess` is a per directory config.

Comment: I just contacted my hosting company they said i only have access to the .htaccess file since i am on shared hosting. can i use that same command

 `<VirtualHost *:*> ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/</VirtualHost> `

in an .htaccess file

Comment: If subdomains maps to the real path in a file system so you can check the existence of that path and make redirects. `VirtualHost` not allowed in htaccess context.

Comment: Thanks for the response Deadooshka, I really apologise i am a verf fresh webdeveloper. i am reading the htaccess guide at [http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html] which is good, but i do not know all the commands yet to put in the htaccess file to let it check if the subdomain exists and then redirect if it does not